# Noob can't read_csv

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

Google collab. Pandas. Windows 10. Saved an Excel file as .csv. Even put it on my desktop for easy access. Absolute filepath.

```
df_teams = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\adamg\Desktop\Team_names.csv')
```

Getting

> "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\adamg\Desktop\Team_names.csv'"

Comment: I'm not sure.... is google collab incapable of doing normal read_csv with direct path? i'd like to learn that method, so seeking to troubleshoot why it's not working

Comment: It can't read files off of your local machine directly, you have to the put the file on Google Drive or on the virtual machine with the method in the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv("Team_names.csv")
df.head(5) # it show first five rows when dataset uploaded
```

NOTE: name of a file that you want to read is the same the file you save in your local system(eg: you save "Team_names.csv" in your E- drive) and don't use a complete file path.

Here what we are doing :

once you write the above piece of code it will ask you to upload a file. Here suppose your file name ie "Team_names.csv" and it stores in your E-drive. So when it asks you to upload a file it will give you the option to "choose file". Once click on "choose file" you can easily access your all drive and you can select your file, it will automatically upload in your colab.